# tangent/normal space to set of symmetric isospectral matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $\Lambda = \{\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n\}$ be a set of $n$ **distinct** real numbers. $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of all $n \times n$ real matrices, and for $B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, $B^T$ denotes the transpose of B, and $\sigma(B)$ is the (multi)set of the eigenvalues of $B$.

I'm trying to figure out the tangent space and the normal space to the set

$$S = \{ B \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) \, : \, B^T = B, \sigma(B) = \Lambda\},$$
at the point $A= \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$, the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\lambda_i$'s.

Note that $S$ is a manifold in a neighborhood of $A$.

This is my thought process: 
Define a path in $S$ as follows: 
$$A(t)= Q(t) \, A \, Q(t)^T,$$ for a family of orthogonal matrices $Q(t)$, such that $Q(0) = I$, the identity matrix. Then $A(0) = A$.

\begin{align*}\dot{A}(t) &= \dot{Q}(t) \, A \, Q(t)\\ &+\, {Q}(t) \, \dot{A} \, Q(t)\\ &+ \,  {Q}(t) \, A \, \dot{Q}(t) \end{align*}
But $\dot{A} = O$, hence

$$\dot A(0) = \dot Q(0) \, A + A \, \dot Q(0)^T.$$

So, if I know all the tangents/normals to orthogonal matrices at $0$, that is, at $I$, I can describe all the tangents/normals to $S$ at $A$. But it is not too hard to show that the set of all skew-symmetric matrices (i.e. $\{B : B^T = -B\}$) is the tangent space to the orthogonal matrices at $I$. Hence, the tangent space to $S$ at $A$ is $$ T_A(S) = \{ B \, A + A \, B^T : B^T = -B \}.$$

So here are my questions:

**Question 0:** Is my argument above correct?

**Question 1:** Why are these *all* of the tangent vectors? I think(?) $S$ is an $n(n-1)/2$ dimensional manifold, and $T_A(S)$ is $n(n-1)/2$ dimensional, is that really the reason for $T_A(S)$ begin the whole tangent space? Can you elaborate on it, please?

**Question 2.1:** What is the normal space to the set of orthogonal matrices, at $I$?

**Question 2.2:** How do you find the normal space to $S$ at $A$? Is it the same as the following? 
$$\{B \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) : C\, B = O, \forall C \in T_A\}.$$

**Edit:** Direct calculations yield that $T_A(S)$ is the set of all symmetric matrices with zero diagonals, as long as $\lambda_i$'s are all distinct.

Answer (score 0):

A full explanation from a higher perspective can be found in Li, Rodman and Tsing, *Linear operators preserving certain equivalence relations originating in system theory*, Linear Algebra and Its Applications, 161:165-225, 1992.

Comment: Thanks, that's a long paper, and is using some non-familiar notations, but as expected there's quite a bit of Lie theory involved. And well, if C.K. Li writes something, there should be some good mathematics involved. I'll read it and see how it helps. Thank you for the reference.